# Javascript autocomplete auto suggest not working

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ide

Hi I am fairly new with **JavaScript**, dom, html5 programming. I have tried a few IDEs such as visual studio for the web and the netbeans, but seems like no matter what IDE I use, none of them can do auto complete for `.value` or `.innerHTML`.  When I do search with ctrl+space they just couldn't find them. The examples are listed below:

```
//can't find .value after I type text-input
var songName = textInput.value;

//can't find .innerHTML
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = songName;
```

Is that normal? Do I just need to type those in manually or is that because I didn't include necessary libraries for the IDE to work properly?

Comment: They need some way to decide what type `textInput` is.  For example, an `Array` doesn't have a `innerHTML` property.  Some assume everything has everything, and some IDEs don't.  I personally recommend the [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) line of IDEs, but they only come with a 30 day free trial.

Comment: visual studio does provide autocomplete.but even if it does't ,isn't enough reason to not type it manually because javascript is a dynamic language.